# Compare old cache with new data in android Volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I'm using `Volley` library for caching in my news application. I want to cache all the news in the first run and then every time that i open the application display the count of new news in my application.to do that i get all data again and compare it to my cached data . is there any other way to get just part of data which is new in compare with my cache or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the data in cache of volley. You can do this.

```
if(Requestqueue.getCache().get(YourUrl)!=null){
  //if the response is already cached you can access it from cache
  String cachedResponse = new String(Requestqueue.getCache().get(YourUrl).data);

        //Here you can write your code to compare your new data with your cached Data.

 }
```

I hope this was helpful. ThankYou.

Comment: I know that , I want to Know is there any way to get just new data in compare with cache not all data

Comment: Ok. can please explain me what you want to do? You want check the fetched response with the cached data right?

Comment: OhK. i got you now. For that you will have to design you webservice in a right way.

Comment: you dont want to fetch the data which is already stored in cache right?

Comment: no , it take too much  can you explain me more about design webservice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107451/discussion-between-serenei-and-jois).